# Does Azure DevOps have a feature to allow importing exported data from Monday.com

Tags: import, azure-devops, monday.com

We have exported data from Monday.com and I was wondering if I would need to write a custom script to import this information or if Azure DevOps has a feature that would help me with this import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the data you export contain and what is the data type? Take workitem as an example. If you export work items, save it as a .csv file, and then want to import it into AzureDevOps, you can refer to the following steps:

1.Create a local import.csv file and open it in Visual Studio Code or Excel.
2.The file must contain the Work Item Type and the Title fields. You can include other columns as needed.
You can check in [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops) for more details.

Attention: Your CSV file must contain the ID, Work Item Type, Title, and State fields. If not, you need to edit this appropriately.